# Фильтрация по связанному объекту без копирования кода Django

Tags: python, django, orm

У меня есть класс фильтрующий модель Video, пример строчки:

```
# ...
queryset = queryset.filter(genres__in=genres)
# ...
```

Появилась необходимость фильтровать по полям Video модель Room

```
class Room(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(
        Video, verbose_name="Видео", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    #...
```

Но теперь приходится просто копировать огромный код фильтрации Video и дописывать в фильтрах "video__"

```
queryset = queryset.filter(video__genres__in=genres)
```

Есть ли способ избежать этого и сделать более гибко?

Comment: если есть `video_queryset = Video.objects.filter(genres__in=genres)` то `room_query_set = Room.objects.filter(video__in=video_queryset)`

Comment: Это сработало, спасибо. Джанго даже поместил это во вложенный запрос